# How to configure LDAP for pgadmin login without ssl

Tags: ldap, docker-swarm, pgadmin, swarm, docker-network

I run pgadmin with docker swarm and host can connect to external ldap server swarm cluster.

conig_distro.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_SOURCES = ['ldap', 'internal'] 
LDAP_AUTO_CREATE_USER = True
LDAP_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10
LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://x.x.x.x:389'
LDAP_USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE = [ 'uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName' ]
LDAP_BIND_USER = 'CN=svnadmin,OU=IS,OU=Services,OU=Users,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=net'
LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'password'
LDAP_ANONYMOUS_BIND = False
LDAP_BASE_DN = 'OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx'
LDAP_SEARCH_BASE_DN = ''
LDAP_SEARCH_FILTER = '(objectclass=*)'
LDAP_SEARCH_SCOPE = 'SUBTREE'
LDAP_USE_STARTTLS = False
LDAP_CA_CERT_FILE = ''
LDAP_CERT_FILE = ''
LDAP_KEY_FILE = ''
```

and when wants login have this error:

> ERROR  flask.app:      Error connecting to the LDAP server: socket connection
> error while opening: timed out

complete logs is:

```
[2020-09-28 04:39:38 +0000] [81] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81
2020-09-28 04:40:19,633: ERROR  flask.app:      Error connecting to the LDAP server: socket connection
 error while opening: timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pgadmin4/pgadmin/authenticate/ldap.py", line 110, in connect
    self.conn = Connection(server,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._do_auto_bind()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 380, in _do_auto_bind
    self.open(read_server_info=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 56, in open
    BaseStrategy.open(self, reset_usage, read_server_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 145, in open
    raise exception_history[0][0]
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSocketOpenError: socket connection error while opening: timed out
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you were able to see those logs? I am trying to setup LDAP authentication in pgadmin4 myself and can't find where to look for logs. Thanks,

Comment: I run this service on swarm cluster;  show logs with `docker logs -f CONTAINER_NAME`